# Всегда в галереи последний пост после цикла в html | Angular 8 | @ngx-gallery/core

Tags: html, angular2, angular, gallery

Есть список постов, которые успешно при загрузке страницы загружаются c базы.
В каждом посте есть свой массив с фотками. Я использую для галереи либу @ngx-gallery/core. В каждом посте по сути в цикле вставляется компонент с либой для галереи. В просмотре всех постов в ленте все стоит на своих местах. Но как только я  кликну по картинке,то открывается просмотр где всегда фотки с последнего поста.

Вот код html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of postsGroup; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"  style="margin-top: 15px;" class="card col-md-8 p-0">
<div class="card-header">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar-post">
  {{item.postTitle}}
</div>
<div class="card-body row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p class="card-text">
      {{item.postBody}}
    </p>
    <div *ngIf="item.photos.length > 0" class="row">
      <p id="{{i"  class="container" gallerize>
        <img style="padding:1px; height: 70px; width: auto;" class="col-md-3"  *ngFor="let img of item.photos" [src]="img.srcUrl">
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
    2 days ago
  </div>
</div>
```

Посты у меня в переменную записываются явно.

```
suc => {
    this.postsGroup = suc;
    this.ngxLoader.stop('group');
  },
  err => {
    this.ngxLoader.stop('group');
  });
```

Перепробовал уже 300 вариантов. И отдельный массив делал в коде, все равно грузит с последнего поста фотки в просмотр в полном режиме. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю галерею с последнего поста. Что я делаю не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение после перечитывания документации и танцев с бубном. В итоге получил полноценное решение, которое работает идеально и безотказно. Отвечаю на собственный вопрос, может кому пригодится.

1. В самом посту мы просто вырисовываем изображения в цикле и убераем атрибут gallerize вот так:

```html
<div *ngIf="item.photos.length > 0" class="row">
          <p class="container">
            <img (click)="open(i,t)" [attr.data-index]="i" style="padding:1px; height: 70px; width: auto;"
              class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let img of item.photos; let t = index" [src]="img.srcUrl">
          </p>
        </div>
```

Вешаем на него ивент по клику. Вот код самого ивента open

```html
 async mappingImg(index): Promise<GalleryItem[]> {
    return this.postsGroup[index].photos.map(item => new ImageItem({ src: item.srcUrl, thumb: item.previewUrl }));
  }

  async open(index, indexPhoto) {
    this.itemsImg = [];
    this.itemsImg = await this.mappingImg(index);
    this.lightboxRef.load(this.itemsImg);
    this.showPhoto = true;
    this.lightbox.open(indexPhoto);
  }
```

Наша галерея с атрибутом gallerize теперь захаркодина и лежит внизу страницы. Именно она и будет открываться для просмотра. И да, она полностью пустая так как весь конфиг мы зададим в ngOnInit

```html
<p *ngIf="showPhoto" gallerize>
  <img >
</p>
```

Ну и самое главное, конфиг в ngOninit()

```html
 this.lightboxRef = this.gallery.ref('lightbox');
    this.lightboxRef.setConfig({
      imageSize: ImageSize.Contain,
      loadingMode: 'indeterminate',
      thumbPosition: ThumbnailsPosition.Bottom
    });
    this.lightbox.setConfig({
      panelClass: 'fullscreen',
    });
    this.lightbox.closed.subscribe(event => this.close(event));
```

Как видите мы подписываемся на событие "закрыть" просмотр. Вот метод close(event)

```
close(event) {
    this.itemsImg = [];
    this.showPhoto = false;
  }
```

Скрываем и чистим галерею иначе там будет большой лист вниз по странице)

Ну и незабываем про переменные в начале класса и необходимый импорт

```html
import { Lightbox } from '@ngx-gallery/lightbox';
import { Gallery, GalleryItem, ImageItem, ThumbnailsPosition, ImageSize, GalleryRef } from '@ngx-gallery/core';

export class GroupComponent implements OnInit {
  lightboxRef: GalleryRef;
  itemsImg: GalleryItem[];
  showPhoto = false;
```

В конструкторе

```html
public gallery: Gallery, public lightbox: Lightbox,
```